# ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v7

I have updated my `node`, `npm` and `@angular/cli` on OSx Mojave. 
Now, when creating a new Angular app I get this message:

> ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, mkdir '/home/foo'

I can't figure out what the problem seems to be.

Comment: After a reboot of OSx it seems that the problem has disappeared.

Comment: I have the same issue. `npm install --global alfred-vpn` installs and tries to move a file to `/Volumes/GoogleDrive/My Drive`. Looks like npm has an issue with moving files to a Volume. Did the restart resolve it for you?